# $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, $E(X)=0$, $E(Y)$ is finite, how to prove $E(|X+Y|)\geq E(|Y|)$?

Tags: probability, expectation

I remember the inequality$|a+b|\geq ||a|-|b||$.But this can't be used to this problem.
Are there some other inequalities which can work out ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple proof using conditional Jensen's inequality, but let me give a more elementary proof in case this machinery is not available to you.

Let $F_X$ and $F_Y$ be the c.d.f of $X$ and $Y$, respectively. Then

\begin{align*}
E(|X+Y|)
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} |x+y| \, dF_X(x) dF_Y(y) \\
&\geq \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left| \int_{\mathbb{R}} (x+y) \, dF_X(x) \right| dF_Y(y) \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} |y| dF_Y(y) \\
&= E(|Y|).
\end{align*}